# jquery throws SyntaxError with valid JSON response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

So I have an ajax function communicating with a php file returning json_encode.

The ajax function:

```
$.ajax({            
        type: 'POST',
        data: sendData,
        dataType: 'json',
        mimeType: "application/json",
        url: 'request.php',                 
        success: function(data){
            return data;
        }
    });
```

sendData is something like this:

> { 'action': 'do_stuff',   'id': 5 }

And the result is

> {"affected_rows":1,"insert_id":0}

I have checked for weird termination characters or padding in the result and found nothing. Interestingly enough, the error that is being thrown is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o", which is strange because the result does not begin or end with an o, and the only o is in the middle.

I've also tried not defining the data or mime types and manually parsing the json with both JSON.parse(data); and jQuery.parseJSON(data); with no success.

If it helps, request.php returns its data like this:

```
        $a = $_POST[action];
        $result = call_user_func_array($a, $_POST);
        if($result){
            echo json_encode( $result );
        }else{
            echo json_encode( 'There was an error processing your request (Error: '.get_error_id($a).')'  );
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to turn error_reporting to 0? it may be generating some notice or warnings, What do you get as a response when you analyze page requests in your browser developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o` seems unrelated with the JSON being valid or invalid.

Are you sure there isn't elsewhere another AJAX callback configured to run? (At AJAX global settings?)

I am supposing the error indicates malformed JavaScript (not invalid JSON)...

Comment: True, there could be another script throwing the error after the script above executes

Comment: @JosephPersie: and I say the same to your comment - "True, there could be some PHP notice or warning before the JSON contents." :-) (I upvoted your comment...)

Comment: After scouring for way too long, I found I was trying to parse the JSON twice. That's what I get for copy/pasting old code.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to put :

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
```

Before :

```
if($result) {
```

Comment: The excepted response would be in JSON format, there's officially registered MIME type known as `application/json`